# Prototyped function of structs

Tags: c++, function, struct, prototype

Today I came across [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/whatsnew/) piece of code:

```
int main() {
  struct Foo {};
  struct Bar {};

  Foo(b)(int (Bar*c)); // ?

  return 0;
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what is going on. My compiler (VC14) warns me about unused prototyped function?

What does this line do (declare a function: which name, what parameters and return type? How to call it?)

```
Foo(b)(int (Bar*c));
```

Thank you in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This declares a function called `b` that:

- takes `int (Bar*c)` as its argument;
- returns `Foo`.

The type of the argument, `int (Bar*c)`, is a pointer to a function that takes a pointer to `Bar` and returns an `int`. Here, `c` is the name of the argument and can be omitted: `int (Bar*)`.

Here is how you can call `b`:

```
int main() {
  struct Foo {};
  struct Bar {};

  Foo(b)(int (Bar* c)); // the prototype in question

  int func(Bar*);       // a function defined elsewhere
  Foo result = b(func);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not valid C (because the names `Foo` and `Bar` don't refer to types; you would have to use the `struct` keyword or use a typedef).

In C++, this is a surprising but valid declaration. It declares b as a function returning Foo and taking an argument of type "(pointer to) function returning int taking an argument of type pointer to Bar".

In order to generate a readable type declaration, I've written the following code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    struct Foo {};
    struct Bar {};

    Foo(b)(int (Bar*c));
    std::cout << typeid(b).name();

    return 0;
}
```

Then I've compiled it and filtered its output through `c++filt`.
The result was:

```
main::Foo (int (*)(main::Bar*))
```

which is entirely clear.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why it is not valid C.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Added that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, my compiler (Clang 3.5) gives me the following warning:

> warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration
>   [-Wvexing-parse]

Which is more on point, as you are dealing with with [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

The following declaration:

```
Foo(b)(int (Bar*c));
```

declares a  `b`  **function pointer** pointing to a function that returns `Foo` and takes  as an argument a function that returns `int` and takes pointer to `Bar` an an argument (e.g.: `int (Bar*c)`).

Your compiler probably thinks this is a prototype of a function, thus the warning.